# Using a slider within AJAX

Tags: ajax

How can I use this slider function within my single page app(HTML AJAX callback)?

My code:

```
  <script type="text/template" id="bikes-template">
   <div style="text-align:;">
    <% collection.forEach(function(item){ %> 
    <hr>
    <h3><%= item.brand %> <%= item.type %></h3>
    <img src="<%= item.pic %> " alt="<%= item.name %>" style="width: 150px;">
    <p>current miles: <%= item.currentMiles %></p>
    //put slider here, but how? 
    <% }); %>
    </div>
  </script>
```

slider-

https://jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: so you want to insert that entire <div> via an ajax call? Why would you need ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Using the above template script within my html allows me to add html to the body of my html. But, I don't know how to add this slider that includes a function.

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider();
  });
  </script>

<div id="slider"></div>
```